# return two values with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have problem receiving my data from the database with `getjson` or `jquery ajax`. The alert shows "array" but i want it to show the value of `$latArray`. What am i doing wrong?

here is my php :

```
<?php

    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT userLat, userLng FROM users"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $latArray[] =  $row['userLat'];
           $lngArray[] =  $row['userLng']; 
    }

     echo json_encode(array("lat" => "$latArray", 
      "lng" => "$lngArray"));

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$.getJSON("homesearchplayers.php", function(data) {
                             alert("Value: " + data.lat);
       });
```

Comment: If you put `console.log(data)` inside the function, what is the output?

Comment: try `console.log(data.lat)` - what is logged in the console (alert and friends are useless for debugging)

Comment: you are using `$latArray` as string in `PHP` code when it is a variable. Change it to `array("lat" => $latArray, 
      "lng" => $lngArray)`

Comment: @S4beR you are correct that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo json_encode(array("lat" => "$latArray", 
  "lng" => "$lngArray"));
```

Will convert `$latArray` to a string first, and an array-to-string conversion will lead into the string `"Array"`. Use

```
echo json_encode(array("lat" => $latArray, "lng" => $lngArray));
```

instead.